# How could you get a chair with very high arm rests with large surface area parallel to ground?

Tags: technology, comfort, office-supplies, furniture

Imagine this:
- Sit upright in a chair 
- Stick arms out to the side so your upper body forms a T
- Using your biceps, bend your elbow 90 degrees so your fists are pointing in front of you

That's the position I'm going for. I once had two tall tables next to me and I rested my arms on them - it was very comfy. Purpose: to get the comfy position that I like for leisure.

Most chairs position armrests much lower.

**What are some easy ways I could find/make what I'm looking for?**

Some things to deal with
- I'd like the arm rests to have surface areas like little tables so my entire arms can rest on top of each rest
- Has to be soft enough so its comfy and the edge of the little armrest tables not be uncomfortable

Comment: You can ask also in [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com/) maybe there you can find a better answer

Comment: And if you want to make it yourself you may ask in [Woodworking SE](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Two ironing tables--one on either side of you.

Comment: Hi Pamela! Thank you for your post, however, due to its lack of clarity and description you need to edit it. For help you can look in the Help Center on how to write a successful post. Thank You!

Comment: This sounds exactly like what the OP wants: correct height (assuming adjustable-height [ironing tables](https://ixquick-proxy.com/do/spg/show_picture.pl?l=english&rais=1&oiu=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oldrids.co.uk%2Fimages%2Fproducts%2Flarge%2F8496.jpg&sp=11ce5c0af56833393a40ec0fd17fb280)) + soft enough to be comfortable + large enough to rest a whole arm on each.

Answer (score 0):

The arm rests will be lower with a sofa or armchair, because the seat of the chair is much nearer the floor. What you're describing is either an older person's armchair (much higher off the ground, usually with a seat parallel to the ground, and arms) or an executive office chair, which is exactly what I sit on when relaxing, no longer being able to sit on lower seats. The trouble is, you haven't said you want it to be higher than, say, a sofa or an ordinary armchair, so it may not suit you, but when I sit in mine, my arms are resting on the arm rests at the angle you describe, and the seat is parallel with the floor. The arm rests are not padded, but that could be remedied by doing a bit of home upholstery, or seeking out one which actually has padded arms. The other drawback, of course, is that they are swivel chairs, meaning a wheeled base, and you may not want that in your lounge or sitting room. Personally, I find the wheeled base and swivel action a godsend - I use it both at the dining table and in front of the tv, so moving it from one end of the room to the other is really easy. It's black leather, doesn't go with anything else, but they come in a range of colours and materials. But then I've got a very bad back, and maybe you haven't....

Answer (score 0):

Most chairs today are made and designed for the greatest comfort while seated. There are actual equations that can find the best ergonomic design specifics for a persons stature.

In regards to your question it sounds to me as if you would prefer to sit with your arms at *shoulder level*? If so I'd just like to suggest that a person with knowledge in physiology or ergonomics should be consulted for advice as to any adverse repercussions sitting in this position may have to the body (specifically the shoulder/neck parts).   So modifying an existing chair so the arms are about 12-14 inches higher (or the seat is 12-14 inches lower) is the challenge.

My first thought was imagining a chair-type that would fit your design standards. It took some scanning and than I thought of a few summers in Maine at a friends cabin. The 'Adirondack'-style chair is extremely close to your specifications. With some simple design modifications to the arms and cleaver woodworking skills it shouldn't take very long to construct the chair of your dreams.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you buy a reclining sofa it will meet your needs perfectly. Indeed, once inclined, the arms are almost at the same height as your shoulders. There are several models on the market; personally I opted for this [sofa](https://mobilia.ca/fr/salon/canapes-et-fauteuils/inclinables.html) model at home.